# JUnit on IntelliJ on OS X - Can't assign requested address

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, junit

When I run a JUnit test on IntelliJ on Mac - OS X - 10.11.2 (El Capitan), I run into the following error.

```
Can't assign requested address - 127.0.0.2:27425
```

The JUnit tests I'm running are already setup and they work fine when run on Ubuntu/RHEL/Windows.

I guess the problem is with Mac not recognizing 127.0.0.* as localhost.

I have tried the following in vain.

1. Ran this command to alias localhost for 2 <= i <= 255

   ```
   sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 127.0.0.$i up
   ```
2. Added the below lines to /etc/hosts

   ```
   127.0.0.2    localhost
   127.0.0.3    localhost
   ...
   ...
   127.0.0.255    localhost
   ```

Greatly appreciate any hints/suggestions to fix/work around this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution from super user exchange:

> Here is the short answer: sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.* up
>
> Each alias must be added individually (sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up, sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 up). It can be done manually for testing, or a subset or the complete list of the other 250 available numbers in that subnet can be made into StartupItems script that will do it automagically at boot time.
>
> The long answer: According to RFC3330, 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address. A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback, but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network anywhere.

Here is the [Original post](https://superuser.com/questions/458875/how-do-you-get-loopback-addresses-other-than-127-0-0-1-to-work-on-os-x)